# click the submit button, which hook will I trigger, wordpress plugin development

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I just learn to write a plugin， to write the data submitted by the WordPress plugin contact form 7 into the database. (The default is not to write to the database)

Question 1, when I click the submit button, which hook will I trigger.

Question 2, there are 2 contact-form-7 on my website,

When I click the current submit button, how can I tell which contact-form-7 submit button I click?

i write some very simple wordpress plugin.